# Android - FTP problem in Android

Tags: android, ftp

I am trying to do ftp to local host. but im getting error 
03-03 00:49:40.747: WARN/System.err(4151): java.net.ConnectException: /127.0.0.1:1160 - Connection refused
03-03 00:49:40.758: WARN/System.err(4151):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:255)

And the code follows like this

```
             FTPClient ftp;

            server = "10.0.2.2";

            username = "newuser";

            password = "wampp";

            remote = "/sample.txt";

            local = "/data/data/com.test.sample/files/sample/sample.txt";

                ftp = new FTPClient();


                InputStream input;

                input = new FileInputStream(local);

                ftp.storeFile(remote, input);

                input.close();
```

I am using XAMPP server as my localhost. It Contains FileZilla. Same code works fine as normal java application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear that you're actually using the server, username or password variables.  Take a look at this example to get some direction:

http://hoang17.com/posts/android/android-how-to-upload-a-file-via-ftp

Comment: Hi Richard,I tried the same from the link what you have refered. But again i'm facing same problem.03-03 01:22:56.997: WARN/System.err(13487): java.net.ConnectException: /127.0.0.1:2482 - Connection refused
03-03 01:22:57.007: WARN/System.err(13487):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:255)

Comment: You're now calling `.connect()` and `.login()`?

Answer (score 0):

How is your android device connected to the network?? Can you even ping 10.0.2.2 from the device itself??

I suggest installing busybox on your android device, it has telnet and ftp commands to test your FTP server. If you cannot access your ftp from busybox/android shell, than you have firewall or port forwarding issues.

Comment: Hi ,Im using emulator. I can ping 10.0.2.2 from adb shell, even i can open it from my android browser.

Comment: Hi Saideira, Still im not able to resolve that. can u please suggest me . can u tel me where im going wrong